# How to Exclude all the properties from being passed by the model binder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have an object where all its values will be system-generated inside the code, and no user (hackers!!) should be able to modify any of its values. so defined an empty list in the Bind `[Bind(Include = "")]` list as follow :-

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Technology_Validation))]
[Bind(Include = "")]
    public partial class Technology
```

but i am not sure is passing empty list after the Include ,, means that the model binder will exclude all the properties ,, i can not test it ?

Comment: If the model should not be passed into the view, then don't make it an argument to the action method. More likely, you just want to pass an id of the model, so you can fetch it inside of the view from the database, in which case just accept the id. Not sure what the issue is here.

Comment: Like Chris, I thin k we're missing details here. Like: 1. Is the code to generate the values server or client side? 2. Is this model the entire viewmodel, or is it a related class passed as part of a wider view model?